# Combining multiple lists into one

Tags: joined-view

I have two custom lists on the SharePoint website and I would like to create a list which combines/joins the two lists. Is this possible and if so what are the best methods or third party tools for achieving this?

Regards,
Sharmila

Comment: Are you actually trying to combine the lists? Or just trying to **show** them as joined in a view somewhere?

Comment: I need to join lists and i want to access the resulting data in a custom webpart

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You can export the lists in Excel sheets. Combine them and create another list using the combined excel sheet. This way will only allow you to combine data upto that particular point of time. i.e, its not dynamic.
2. You can combine lists using a Data view web part creating a new linked resource. Refer [this blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20180914202818/http://blah.winsmarts.com/2007-10-Performing_joins_between_SharePoint_lists.aspx) for details. And afterwards you can export this combined Data View web part using javascript. Find all the details [here](http://ameyakawale.wordpress.com/2011/08/04/exporting-dataview-webpart-data-into-excel-using-javascript/) for exporting. Exporting from a Data View web part would be dynamic and real time.

Good Luck .

Comment: Thank you:) I have the linked datasource and now I need to access this datasource in a custom webpart

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SPSiteDataQuery` to combine or join multiple lists created out of same list template.

It is beautifully explained in the following link:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/401818/SharePoint-SPSiteDataQuery-with-Example

Comment: Looks like the link is dead :(

Comment: This is the reason a link is never enough in an answer. Fortunately, you can get the article using the Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20150605043437/https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/401818/SharePoint-SPSiteDataQuery-with-Example