# How can I combine multiple Lists into one view for editing

Tags: list, lookup-column, form

I had a list with 18 lookups which exceeded the SharePoint 2010 threshold.  So I broke it up into 3 lists all having the same "ProjectID" column as a lookup to the first column so that there is only one row of data for each ProjectID in all of the lists.  What I need now is nice way to present all three lists for managing them. Or is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: How many fields total did you have in this 1 list?  18 lookup columns seem like a lot so I'm curious as well what each of these is for.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider either building a InfoPath form and using those lists as secondary sources for look-up data, or using the Linked data source with a DataView web part - however not sure you could also enable editing (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/add-a-linked-data-source-HA010355748.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

you could try what this guy has stated:

[Combining multiple lists into one](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34198/combining-multiple-lists-into-one)

hope it helps :)

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @BennySkogberg comon this is an old question over a year ago and the link is on the same site!

Comment: Since I'm one of the "protector of content", you'll see this types of comments on old answers too Ali! ;-)