# How to collate/merge two different lists, with the same colums into one list

Tags: development, powershell

I have got two different lists. One is live updated by many users. The second list has the same fields and works as the master. I want to every day, at 6:00 o'clock a.m, merge List one with list two.

How could I add items from List one to list two? I want to do it by PowerShell and Timer Job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you have to create a new list (the merge list) the all the items from the two lists and add to the merge list:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://mysite
$list = $web.Lists["firstList"]
$merge = $web.Lists["mergeList"]
$items = $list.GetItems()

foreach ( $item in $item ) {
    # do job

    $newItem = $list.Items.Add() 
    $newItem["Title"] = $item["Title"]
    # others properties
    $newItem.Update()
}
```

Comment: yes indeed this code is Powershell!!!!

Comment: Oh Yes Sorry :) I don't see a sign $ sorry :)

Comment: `($item in $items)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Combine two lists like in the answer on SE [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/34233/16290), or use a tutorial by Melick Rajee Baranasooriya from [nothingbutsharepoint.com](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/How-to-Link-Two-Lists-and-Create-a-Combined-View-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx).

A tutorial on creating custom Timer Jobs can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc406686%28office.12%29.aspx).

Sharepoint list-synchronization with Powershell can be found on  Jesper Christensen's [blog](http://jespermchristensen.wordpress.com/2008/09/11/sharepoint-list-synchronization-with-powershell-1-0/).